# Concerning truth table, Karnaugh map, cost and delay of a logic function

Tags: karnaugh-map

A logic function called \$defragment(n)\$ receives as its input \$n\$ bits, \$d[0],...,d[n-1]\$, and \$n\$ flags, \$v[0],...,v[n-1]\$, indicating whether the input is valid. The function returns only the bits which are valid, according to their order,\$\,y[0],...,y[n-1]\$. In case the number of valid bits, \$k\$, is smaller than \$n\$, the remaining \$y's\$ are assigned \$"don't \,care"\$. Attached is an example for defragment(4).
I was asked to first write the truth table for defragment(2), then its SOP, then try and evaluate its cost and delay based on its recursive expression which I'm expected to determine.
Are the Karanugh maps attached, and the SOPs, correct?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Anyone? What ought to be added in order to get some assistance?

Comment: Should I delete this question or is there still a chance someone might be willing to review my work?

Comment: To me your Truth table seems fine. It corresponds to the description of the functionality you explained in your question.

Comment: @KillaKem That's highly helpful, thank you so much! I also attached the Karnaugh maps and the corresponding SOPs. I'd be grateful for feedback on them too, if possible.

Comment: @peripatein: I'm sure your teacher will give you feedback once they return the assignment

Comment: I'd prefer knowing if possible prior to submitting it ;-).. Moreover, I am quite stuck on the evaluation of the recursive expression for fragment(n)
and its cost/delay and in order to receive your help with that I figured I needed to first show my work for the previous sections, as well as make sure they were indeed correct

Comment: Your top K-map only ought to be D1. The other loops are just including don't care terms which, as you know, you don't care about. Same with the orange loop on the second K-map. It's not covering any necessary information (not to mention you could have turned it into a "hot dog" 1x4 loop).

Comment: So now that I know that for defragment(2), \$Y_1=D_1,\,Y_0=V_0D_0+\neg{V_0}D_1\$, how do I infer the recursive relation for defragment(n)? I tried evaluating defragment(1) and got \$Y_0=D_0+\neg{D_0} \neg{V_0}\$ but that didn't seem to get me nearer to figuring it out. A word of advice, anyone?